# Select keys within an array then write that out to a config file as an array

Tags: jq

I'm trying to wrap my head around the following.  I'd like to place the output below into an array that I can save as a list of thermostats (which I currently only have 1, but I'd like to plan on the ability to have 2)

```json
jq '.thermostatList[] | {name, identifier}' test.json
{
  "name": "Thermostat",
  "identifier": "123456789"
}
```

What I'd like

```json
cat ~/etc/ecobee.thermostats
{
   "thermostats": [
      {
         "name": "Thermostat",
         "identifier": 123456789
      }
   ]
}
```

Is this possible with jq?

Thanks

Comment: is your requirement just to rename the key of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take `thermostatList` as context and `map`:

```sh
jq '.thermostatList | {thermostats: map({name, identifier})}' test.json
```

```json
{
  "thermostats": [
    {
      "name": "Thermostat",
      "identifier": 123456789
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/mO90Okv9tS)

Comment: Thanks again .. My first foray with json and I have a lot more reading to do ;-)